# Creating a new null object what will the instance variables be?

Tags: java, constructor, null

Let's say I have a class named `Class` and I created a new null object:

`Class object = null`

The constructor in `Class` is:

```
private int a;
private String b;

public Class() {
    a = 144;
    b = "Test";
    c = null;
}
```

Will `a`, `b`, and `c` be equal to null?

If not, is there a way for me to create the object so that all three instance variables are `null`?

Comment: `a` is an `int` so it can't be null.

Comment: The best way to find out 'is this possible' or 'what does this code do' is to write it and find out. Step through the code in a debugger and examine the content of your variables and see what values they hold.

Answer (score 2):

No.  They won't be equal to anything because they won't exist.  Nothing ever created an instance of `Class` so there is no instance.

As an analogy you're basically asking, "If I don't build a house, will that house's windows be open or closed?"  They will be neither.

When you do this:

```
Class object = null;
```

What you have is a *variable* which *can* (at a later time) refer to any instance of type `Class`, but which currently refers to *no* instance.

> is there a way for me to create the object so that all three instance variables are null

*Kind of*.  You can add a constructor which doesn't set those values:

```
public Class () { }
```

And you can create an instance of that class via that constructor:

```
Class object = new Class();
```

Then you can observe your instance in the debugger to see what those values are.  I'm not *100%* sure in Java, but it's possible that an `int` *can't* be `null`.  Which would make that part of the question kind of moot.  (I know it can't in C#, but if it can in Java then ignore this part and carry on.)

An unassigned `int` local variable would be a compiler error if you try to use it.  But this is a class field, not a local variable.  In this case it's going to be automatically given its default value, which is generally `null` for reference types but `0` for primitive numeric types.

Answer (score 1):

> Let's say I have a class named Class

Given that `java.lang.Class` already exists, let's not. Let's say you have a class named MyClass.

> and I created a new null object:

That's an oxymoron.

`null` is a **reference**. It's not an object. It is, in fact, the reference that means 'I refer to no object', and is the only reference that means 'I point at nothing'.

When you write:

```
MyClass x = new MyClass();
```

Then `x` is a **treasure map**, and `new MyClass()` is 'create a new treasure chest and bury it in the sand'. The `=` in the middle says: Update the treasure map named `x`, so that following it would lead you to the treasure I just made (`new X()` means: Make new treasure and bury it).

```
MyClass x = null;
```

means you have a treasure map named `x` which is currently blank.

> If not, is there a way for me to create the object so that all three instance variables are null?

That would imply a treasure chest of the `MyClass` treasure type, which has room for some scratches (`int a` - a number), and which contains a treasure map (the `String b` variable). If you want to set them all to `null`, well, you can't - `a` is a primitive (`int`) and those aren't treasure maps, they are the actual number. You can't not have one - a cannot be null. At best, a can be `0`. b CAN be null. That means there's real treasure, but the treasure contains yet another treasure map (in java it's mostly treasure maps all the way), but that one is blank. That's different from there being no treasure at all.

More generally, the question: "Can I make a new instance of MyClass such that all fields are some value I desire" is the wrong question to ask, perhaps: The general principle is encapsulation: `MyClass` is an API: It's like the receptionist at a big corp's office. The receptionist decides what services are available. Even if the CEO is available, if the receptionist elects not to answer the question 'can I see the CEO right now please?', then you can't see her.

Your question boils down to: "If I storm into this office and I demand to speak to the CEO, will I be allowed to?" - the only viable answer is: Well, the receptionist would decide, so you'd have to ask him. For classes: Whatever the API lets you do, you can do. But that's all you can do.

If there is no constructor that initializes these fields to null, then, no, you can't.